# Memory usage is high, any way to optimize this script - python

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am trying to compare each record with all other records, while comparing i am returning the index of the elements which are different in both records.

```
def combinations(records):
    import itertools
    return(itertools.combinations(records,2))

mytuples = tokenize("C:\\Users\\***\\Desktop\\***.data")
data = combinations(mytuples)
new = [([i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in data]
```

Initially i thought, reading the file to python takes time and so i tried to execute my code with only reading part, it took only seconds. But when i add this comparison part, its taking lot of memory as it has to compare each record and each element in it. I could see my computer memory usage goes high and reaches the limit (8GB). And my CPU usage is within 50%, so i guess i can assume that the computation is not that intense and so not required to parallelize the process (Correct me if i am wrong).

Is there any way, i can optimize this?

Added after the comment

```
def tokenize(filename):
    import csv
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        f_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter='\t')
        headers = next(f_csv)
        tuple_attr = tuple(headers)
        mytuples = tuple(tuple(x) for x in f_csv)
        return(tuple_attr,mytuples)

def combinations(records):
    import itertools
    return(itertools.combinations(records,2))


tuple_attr,mytuples = tokenize("C:\\****\\trial.data")
data = combinations(mytuples)
new = ((tuple_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in data)
#print(new)
skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in new)
print(skt)
newset = set(s for s in skt if not any(p < s for p in skt))
print(newset)
```

Here is my data..

```
Age Workclass   Fnlwgt  Education   Education-num
39   State-gov  77516    Bachelors  13
50   Self-emp-not-inc   83311    Bachelors  13
38   Private    215646   HS-grad    9
```

And this is my output.

{frozenset({'Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt'}), frozenset({'Age', 'Workclass', 'Education-num', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education'})}

{frozenset({'Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt'})}

Comment: Do you actually need the results in a list, or just in something you can iterate over?

Comment: Also, how big is `data`?

Comment: I need my results to be in a set of sets. I am converting them after this using skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in new). Because i need to use these sets later to find the minimal subsets.                     And the data is 3.5mb, it has 35000 records and each record has 15 elements.

Comment: You are saying that this code runs fast without the last line, but slow with the last line, right?

Comment: This cannot be the code you are actually running, because there is a syntax error in the last line (mismatched parentheses). **Please post the actual, correct code you are running; we can't help you if we don't know what it is.**

Comment: Yes true. also, memory usage goes to my computer's maximum limit when i include this last line.

Comment: Please post the actual code that you are running. What is there right now is obviously not it, so we are speculating about code that is not what you are actually running.

Comment: No actually i missed the paranthesis while writing here. Here you go. This is my code, updated now. sorry for that.

Comment: Thanks. I don't understand what you are using the generator expression  for in the last line: `([i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair) if t[0]!=t[1])`. The variable `pair` is always a 2-element tuple, right? So this generator will *always* `yield` [0], and then `yield` [1], if `t[0]!=t[1]`... otherwise it will `yield` nothing.

Comment: @DanLenski: The `pair` is a 2-element tuple, but those elements are 15-element tuples. So it will yield `[0][0], [1][0]`, then `[0][1], [1][1]`, … `[0][14], [1][14]`.

Comment: The reason is that i want to extend this further in near future for different requirement which is to use the index to get the column names of that different element. For example, I will store the column names as a tuple in a different variable like this tuple_attr = ('Age', 'Workclass', 'Fnlwgt', 'Education', 'Education-num', 'marital-status', 'Occupation', 'Relationship', 'Race', 'Sex', 'Capital-gain', 'Capital-loss', 'Hours-per-week', 'Native country', 'Probability') . So i can extend my code like this new = [(tuple_attr[i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in data]

Comment: @Jeeva: Why not just convert each record into an instance of a `class` (probably either a `namedtuple`, or a normal class using `__slots__`), instead of keeping the attributes in a separate tuple?

Comment: After your edit, you're now building a list of millions of generators. I can't imagine how that's useful. Maybe you can strip this down to work with, say, 3 records instead of thousands, put those 3 records into your source code, and show us your output and what you're planning to do with it.

Comment: @abarnert : Sorry, i never used that approach. In that way, is it possible to compare each tuple element by element and return its names?

Comment: @Jeeva: I don't understand that question. But I can explain this: a `namedtuple` acts just like a tuple, except that it also has 15 named attributes, so `t.age` and `t[0]` are the same thing `t.workclass` and `t[1]` are the same thing, etc. You can compare two values of the same `namedtuple` type and they'll automatically compare element by element, because they're tuples.

Comment: Meanwhile, you can build a custom class for anything you want, and define its `__eq__` to anything you want. `__slots__` just lets you say "I have a fixed set of attributes for all of my instances, so store just the values in each instance, in some compact way, instead of in the usual dict mapping attribute names to values."

Comment: @Jeeva, I suspect the giant list of generators is part of the problem here, as your revised code shows you're using.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only massive amount of memory you're using here is the list that you're trying to build.

> the data is 3.5mb, it has 35000 records and each record has 15 elements.

If `mytuples` is a list of 35000 15-tuples, then `combinations` is going to iterate over 612,517,500 pairs of 15-tuples.

The "comparison part", where you unzip that pair of 15-tuples into an iterator over 15 2-tuples, is not going to run out of memory. That's a few KB at worst, not 8GB.

But the fact that you're trying to store a list of a few hundred million single-element lists whose elemnets are integers… well, in 64-bit CPython 3.4, each integer (up to 1<<62) is 28 bytes, and a list takes 8 bytes per element plus a 64-byte header, so you're talking 100 bytes per value, so as soon as you get to around 80 million, that's 8GB.

Your updated version is instead storing a giant list of generators (why?!); generators are at least 64 bytes, or more depending on how much state they have, so it's going to be in the same ballpark.

---

You can reduce that by storing them in a more compact object. An [`array.array('I')`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html) or a numpy [`np.ndarray('I4')`](http://www.numpy.org/) will only use 4 bytes per value instead of 36, so you can get to 2 billion (more than you have) before you run out of memory.

Of course this will only work to store an array of integers, not an array of lists of integers, or an array of generators that yield lists of integers. If you really need lists of integers, you can do that with a 2D array in numpy, but not in `array.array`. If you really need generators of lists of integers, neither one works.

But I think you can eliminate the top level entirely. What do you need `new` for?

> I need my results to be in a set of sets. I am converting them after this using skt = set(frozenset(temp) for temp in new)

If the only thing you're ever doing with `new` is iterating over it once, you can just use an iterator instead of a list. The easiest way to do that is to change the list comprehension into a generator expression (that is, change those outer square brackets `[…]` into parentheses `(…)`). Then you won't be using *any* memory, except for the memory for the current value and a bit of iterator state.

Given that in the latest versions, you're just storing a bunch of generators, which can only each be iterated once, I can't imagine why you'd need to iterate the collection of them more than once or access them in random order.

But if you can't do this for some reason, and can restructure things, just write the appropriate generator expression and pass it to the `array.array` constructor or the `np.fromiter` function. (If you want, `array.array` can be appended to just like a list, so you could write an explicit `for` statement, but I don't think you need to.)

---

So, maybe this is what you want:

```
new = (([i] for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1]) for pair in data)
```

Or maybe one of these:

```
new = (i for pair in data for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1])

new = (i for pair in data for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1])
new = array.array('I', new)

new = (i for pair in data for i, t in enumerate(zip(*pair)) if t[0]!=t[1])
new = np.fromiter(new, np.int32)
```

Or maybe the last one reshaped to be a 2D Nx1 array instead of a 1D array.

Comment: I changed the list comprehension to generator expression and now the memory usage is low, thats a good part. Thanks for the explanation. But CPU is still in 50% when i try to convert it in to sets. Obviously it was not considered as a problem initially, but i am just wondering if there is any optimized approach to handle this situation.

Comment: @abarnert, am I crazy or do your three possible snippets contain the same mismatched parenthesis syntax error as the original version of the question? They all appear to need an extra `(` at the beginning of the outer generator expression.

Comment: @DanLenski It was my initial mistake and i corrected it after you asked it. I guess abarnert using the same. No worries, i corrected it now.. :)

Comment: @DanLenski: Sorry, I kept changing it to match the original post, and then stopped at some point, and I guess I last copied it when it was broken, rather than after it was fixed… anyway, it actually needs more of a change than that, because after incorporating one of the fixes it doesn't actually make sense anymore. I'll accept the edit and then edit some more…

Comment: @Jeeva: For an optimized approach… well, what exactly are you trying to optimize here? Is the process taking more time than seems reasonable for comparing 600 million pairs of tuples?

Comment: No, comparison is not taking time. when i convert it to set of sets, it is taking time, so i was just asking if there is any other option to optimize that further. since i need to find the minimal sets, i am converting the output to set of sets.

Comment: @Jeeva: Keep in mind that you're building a generator (of generators), which is lazy—that is, creating the generator is nearly instantaneous; it's only when you later iterate over that generator that it does the work as-needed for each value. So, when you create the sets by feeding them the generator, that's when it does all the work to generate the 600M values and compare them and so on.